# Classification of a sequence of images (fixed number)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I successfully trained a CNN for a single image classification, using pre-trained resnet50 from tensorflow_hub.

Now my goal is to give as input to my network a *chronological* sequence of images (not a video), to classify the behavior of the subject.
Each sequence consists of 20 images taken every 100ms.

What is the best kind of NN? Where can I find documentation/examples for problems similar to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time there is sequential data some type of Recurrent Neural Network is a great candidate (usually in the form of an LSTM).

Your model may look like a combination of an CNN-LSTM because your pictures have some sort of sequential relationship.

[Here is a link to some examples and tutorials](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/). He will set up a CNN in his example but you could probably rig your architecture to use the resNet you have already made. Though your are not dealing with a video your problem shares the same domain.

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yuanliu_Liu3/publication/308453418_Video-based_emotion_recognition_using_CNN-RNN_and_C3D_hybrid_networks/links/59eea7840f7e9b369575ac1a/Video-based-emotion-recognition-using-CNN-RNN-and-C3D-hybrid-networks.pdf) is a paper than uses a NN architecture like the one described above you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. It seems to be exactly what I was looking for.
In the application example I see TimeDistributed(cnn, ...) that encapsulate the CNN model: the CNN could be pre-trained?

Comment: If the model you have currently could output the input vectors to the LSTM I don't see the problem.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to understand. I found another paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329954455_Short-Term_Load_Forecasting_based_on_ResNet_and_LSTM .
It seems to be possible.
My goal is to create a network with this shape:

[
TimeDistributed(CNN pretrained (maybe the same that I used in the previous case)) ->
LSTM ->
Dense layer(s)
]

If this is possible I would use the same network for convolutional layer, because network was trained on same images but taken one by one, not in a "time related sequence".